# Action Filter Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to apply an action filter to every action except one. How would I go for it?

For example, suppose I want to apply an authorization filter to every action except the action that lets the user login.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of asp.net mvc 3 you can now apply conditional filters by implementing [the `IFilterProvider` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ifilterprovider%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).  You can find a good example almost exactly what you want on [Phil Haack's blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/25/conditional-filters.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the action filter globally in the Global.asax file but I'll design the filter to accept a parameter to deactivate it. I'll apply the filter on the action where I don't want it and give it the deactivation parameter.